# SVN Commit Failed (Could not parse response status line)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I working in my project with Visual Studio 2010 and AnkhSvn (the last version) when I like to do commit I have this error:

An internal error ocurred:
Commit failed(details follow):
MERGE of '/svn/credinform/trunk/Cotizador/Crd.Cotizador': Could not parse response status line (http:/192.168.1.10:3456)

How I can resolve this problem?
I probe with TortoiseSVN and the same error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem with a proxy or a firewall between the local computer and the svn server. In this case your system administator probably can help you.

Answer (score 0):

What does the apache log at your Subversion server say?

This appears to be some problem at the http (or server) level. I don't think you can answer this question by just using a subversion client.

It might help when you try to access the same url (I would guess http://<192.168.1.10>:3456/svn/credinform/trunk/Cotizador/Crd.Cotizardor ) by a normal webbrowser. This will probably also show some kind of error.

My guess would be some access problem at the server that isn't transfered as a readable error to the client, but your apache server log should give you the full details.

Comment: Hi Bert I tested http://192.168.1.10:3456/svn/credinform/trunk/Cotizador/ and I can enter the SVN repository. Other developers haven't this problem. I can update the project but I can't do commit. When I run the commit I get the error message that I attached.